# TDD for a Device Communicator

Tags: tdd, inversion-of-control

I've been reading about TDD, and would like to use it for my next project, but I'm not sure how to structure my classes with this new paradigm.  The language I'd like to use is Java, although the problem is not really language-specific.

**The Project**

I have a few pieces of hardware that come with a ASCII-over-RS232 interface. I can issue simple commands, and get simple responses, and control them as if from their front panels. Each one has a slightly different syntax and very different sets of commands.  My goal is to create an abstraction/interface so I can control them all through a GUI and/or remote procedure calls.

**The Problem**

I believe the first step is to create an abstract class (I'm bad at names, how about 'Communicator'?) to implement all the stuff like Serial I/O, and then create a subclass for each device. I'm sure it will be a little more complicated than that, but that's the core of the application in my mind.

Now, for unit tests, I don't think I really need the actual hardware or a serial connection. What I'd like to do is hand my Communicators an InputStream and OutputStream (or Reader and Writer) that could be from a serial port, file, stdin/stdout, piped from a test function, whatever. So, would I just have the Communicator constructor take those as inputs? If so, it would be easy to put the responsibility of setting it all up on the testing framework, but for the real thing, who makes the actual connection? A separate constructor? The function calling the constructor again? A separate class who's job it is to 'connect' the Communicator to the correct I/O streams?

**Edit**

I was about to rewrite the problem section in order to get answers to the question I thought I was asking, but I think I figured it out.  I had (correctly?) identified two different functional areas.

1) Dealing with the serial port

2) Communicating with the device (understanding its output & generating commands)

A few months ago, I would have combined it all into one class.  My first idea towards breaking away from this was to pass just the IO streams to the class that understands the device, and I couldn't figure out who would then be responsible for creating the streams.

Having done more research on inversion of control, I think I have *an* answer.  Have a separate interface and class that solve problem #1 and pass it to the constructor of the class(es?) that solve problem #2.  That way, it's easy to test both separately. #1 by connecting to the actual hardware and allowing the test framework to do different things. #2 can be tested by being given a mock of #1.

Does this sound reasonable? Do I need to share more information?

Comment: What operating system will you be using to build and run the tests? Will this be the same in production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With TDD, you should **let your design emerge**, start small, with baby steps and grow your classes test by test, little by little.

CLARIFIED: Start with a concrete class, to send one command, unit test it with a mock or a stub. When it will work enough (perhaps not with all options), test it against your real device, once, to validate your mock/stub/simulator.

Once the class for the first command is operational, start implementing a second command, the same way: first again your mock/stub, then once against the device for validation. Now if you're seeing similarities between your two classes, you can refactor to your abstract class based design - or to something different.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for being a little Linux centric ..

My favorite way of simulating gadgets is to [write character device drivers](http://luv.asn.au/overheads/chrdev-talk.html) that simulate their behavior. This also gives you fun abilities, like providing an ioctl() interface that makes the simulated device behave abnormally.

At that point .. from testing to real world, it only matters which device(s) you actually open, read and write.

It should not be too hard to mimic the behavior of your gadgets .. it sounds like they take very basic instructions and return very basic responses. Again, a simple ioctl() could tell the simulated device that its time to misbehave, so you can ensure that your code is handling such events adequately. For instance, fail intentionally on every n'th instruction, where n is randomly selected upon the call to ioctl().

Comment: That looks like a great idea, except right now everything is Windows (but Java should be portable...right?).  However, this looks like it might be just what I need for a future project. Do you have any other good resources on writing drivers in Linux (that I might not find in a Google)?

Comment: @drhorrible, there is some example code in the Linux source tree, though it doesn't illustrate the full spectrum of drivers. A good example of a character driver is in drivers/watchdog/softdog.c , this shows how to set up an ioctl interface and read input sent to /dev/{major}.{minor}

Comment: @drhorrible, there is (I think) also a simple example character driver, as well as one for USB gadgets. It pays to poke around the source tree.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing your edits I think you are heading in exactly the right direction.  TDD tends to drive you towards a design composed of small classes with a well-defined responsibility.  I would also echo tinkertim's advice - a device simulator which you can control and "provoke" into behaving in different ways is invaluable for testing.